# HWUI overload occurring in Lazy Column despite using reusable components

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

For some reason, every time I test my Jetpack Compose app on a physical device using the HWUI profiler, the bars always seem to surpass the red horizontal line indicating a breach of the performance limit. How can my layout be changed to prevent the bars stay under the red horizontal line? I'm not sure what to do as my component are reusable.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NestedScrollingTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MyScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyReusableScaffold(scaffoldTitle: String, scaffoldFab: @Composable () -> Unit,
                       scaffoldContent: @Composable (contentPadding: PaddingValues) -> Unit) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            LargeTopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = scaffoldTitle)
                },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            scaffoldFab
        },
        content = { contentPadding ->
            scaffoldContent(contentPadding = contentPadding)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun <T> ReusableLazyRow(lazyRowItems: Array<T>,
                        lazyRowItemLayout: @Composable Any.(item: T) -> Unit,
                        onClickLazyRowItem: (T) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp),
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues()
    ) {
        items(lazyRowItems) { itemR ->
            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    onClickLazyRowItem(itemR)
                }) {
                lazyRowItemLayout(itemR)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun <T> ReusableLazyColumn(
    header: @Composable () -> Unit,
    lazyColumnItems: Array<T>,
    lazyColumnItemLayout: @Composable Any.(item: T) -> Unit,
    onClickLazyColumnItem: (T) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 0.dp, bottom = 80.dp)
        ) {
            item { header.invoke() }
            item { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp)) }
            items(lazyColumnItems) { itemC ->
                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable {
                        onClickLazyColumnItem(itemC)
                    }) {
                    lazyColumnItemLayout(itemC)
                }

                // Show horizontal line between items
                Divider(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.2f))
            }
        }

        ButtonScrollToTopList(listState = listState)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ButtonScrollToTopList(
    modifier : Modifier = Modifier,
    listState : LazyListState
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val showButton by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
        }
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(visible = showButton, enter = fadeIn(), exit = fadeOut(),
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(bottom = 50.dp), Alignment.BottomCenter
        ) {
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp),
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        listState.animateScrollToItem(index = 0)
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.VerticalAlignTop,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
                Text(stringResource(id = R.string.back_to_top))
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    MyReusableScaffold(
        scaffoldTitle = "Demo",
        scaffoldFab = { /*TODO*/ },
        scaffoldContent = {
            MyScreenContent(contentPadding = it)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {

    Box(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(contentPadding)
    ) {
        Column(content = {
                ReusableLazyColumn(
                    header = {
                        ReusableLazyRow(
                            lazyRowItems = rowItems,
                            lazyRowItemLayout = {
                                OutlinedCard(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .height(350.dp)
                                        .padding(16.dp),
                                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp),
                                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                                    containerColor = Color.Unspecified
                                ) {
                                    Column {
                                        Box(
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .background(Color.LightGray)
                                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                                .height(30.dp)
                                        )
                                        Text(
                                            modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
                                            text = it.rowItemTitle
                                        )

                                        Text(
                                            modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
                                            text = it.rowItemDesc,
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            onClickLazyRowItem = { listenerRowItems }
                        )
                    },
                    lazyColumnItems = columnItems,
                    lazyColumnItemLayout = {
                        Row {
                            Text(
                                text = it.columnItemTitle,
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(16.dp)
                                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                            )
                        }
                    },

                    onClickLazyColumnItem = { listenerColumnItems }
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you running a debug or a release build? Debug builds aren't optimized, so the slow UI is normal. But if you're having this issue on a release build, please post your LazyColumn code in order for anyone to be able to help you

**UPDATE**:
I'm pretty sure it's happening because you have nested `LazyRow` inside `LazyColumn`. Try using just a regular `Row` instead. I'm not sure why you would want `LazyRow` in the first place -- I don's see there being a huge amount of horizontal content that would ever benefit from it.

Comment: Code has been added to my question

Comment: And which build?

Comment: This is for the **release** build